# Java expand FilenameFilter

Tags: java, filtering, filenames

I have a method where upon calling a `FilenameFilter` is passed to (as anonymous inner class). Now, if a variable is set, I want to extend the `FilenameFilter`. Example:

```
new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    }
}
```

Should become:

```
new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt") || new File(dir, name).isDirectory();
    }
}
```

How can I get the filtering from the first filter and add the directory check? (I don't want to implement the `FilenameFilter` with directories upon calling the method, because it might not be needed at all)

Solution based upon accepted answer. `filenameFilter` is the instance passed to the method:

```
new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return filenameFilter.accept(dir, name) || new File(dir, name).isDirectory();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extends the first filter:

```
class FilenameFilter1 implements FilenameFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
    }
}

class FilenameFilter2 extends FilenameFilter1 {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return super.accept(dir, name) && new File(dir, name).isDirectory();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do this on `java.io.FilenameFilter`? so the user implements that one and i extend it and add my own filter part?

Comment: FilenameFilter1 in example implements FilenameFilter